# Multiple Google Maps polylines and infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, google-polyline

When trying to add multiple infowindows to polylines, the infowindow doesn't show.

Already tried this thread with the same question:
[Multiple polylines and infowindows with Google Maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068110/multiple-polylines-and-infowindows-with-google-maps-v3)

As you can see I tried to use the suggested function in the given answer, but still it won't work.

Here is my code:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.97559, 4.12565);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: center,
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// start coordinates
var start = ['51.97559, 4.12565', 
             '55.46242, 8.43872', 
             '49.49259, 0.1065',
             '50.36862, -4.13412']

// end coordinates
var end = ['51.94784, 1.2539', 
           '51.94784, 1.2539', 
           '50.79726, -1.11048',
           '43.45846, -3.80685']

function initialize() {


    // Make clickable tooltip
   /*

    */ 

    for (var i=0; i < end.length; i++){
      calcRoute(start[i], end [i]);
    }


}

function calcRoute(source,destination){

      var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeWeight: 5,
        strokeOpacity: 0.5
    });


   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
    var request = { 
        origin:source, 
        destination: destination, 
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING 
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            path = result.routes[0].overview_path;

            $(path).each(function(index, item) {
                poly.getPath().push(item);
                bounds.extend(item);
            })

                // Custom infoWindow
    var toolTip = '<div id="map-box">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Route</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';


       poly.setMap(map);
       createInfoWindow(poly,toolTip); 


            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    });  


}


function createInfoWindow(poly,content) {

    google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.content = content;
        //infowindow.position = event.latLng;
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

here is the jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/cnwMG/7/

Any help to show the infowindow on a polyline would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lacked the most basic : Instantiating the infowindow :)

Then, the right way to set infowindow properties is like this

```
infowindow.setContent(toolTip);
infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
```

not

```
infowindow.content = toolTip;
```

You also had some problems with the logic of calling the infowindow.
Here is a cleaned up forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b7FHV/

[image]

Comment: This is awesome and makes perfect sense, thanks alot! Marked as solved :)